# Querying max, min and other via Core Data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

Is it possible to query the database for the max, min and other values using Core Data framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed have an `NSFetchRequest` calculate such values. You need to set your fetch request to return `NSDictionaryResultType` results, and create appropriate `NSExpressionDescription` objects to describe the operations (e.g. min, max, sum, etc.) you're after.

Take a look at the worked example in Apple's Core Data Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6 .

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the collection operators in objective c. More info here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [query builder](https://github.com/appleios/ALCoreDataManager#query-builder), which allows you write your requests like this:

```
NSDictionary *productTotalSumAndAveragePriceGroupedByCountries = 
[[[[[Product all
] aggregatedBy:@[
                 @[kAggregateSum, @"amount"],
                 @[kAggregatorAverage, @"price"]]
] groupedBy:@[@"country"]
] having:predicate
] execute];
```