# Fetching a maximum value with CoreData

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

This is the first time I'm trying to use CoreData and I'm having some trouble getting the max date from a a table.

This is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Radar" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"modifiedOn"];
NSExpression *maxDate = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"maxDate"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:maxDate];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];

[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (objects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}
else {
    if ([objects count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"%d", [objects count]);
        NSLog(@"MAx date: %@", [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"modifiedOn"]);
    }
}
```

This code somehow does the opposite of what I want and print the minimum date. Since I've just started with CoreData it's obvious that I got something wrong, but what?

Comment: Check out the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789033/querying-max-min-and-other-via-core-data

Comment: @sho - I got it working using the technique described in the answer you pointed me to, however, the official documentation uses the code I pasted on the question. Any ideias on why this code that is almost a copy of the one from the docs is not working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to NSLog the [objects lastObject],instead of first one?