# Iphone : Get maximum from DB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database

i'm geting data from DB in iphone app and i want the maximum number from "Price" column 
and this code not working

```
for(int *i=0; i <= [Rows count]; i++){
    Dict = [Rows objectAtIndex:i];
    if([[Dict objectForKey:@"Price"]intValue] > MaxNum){
        MaxNum = [[Dict objectForKey:@"Price"]floatValue];   
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using?   Can you put your declarations in the sample code, it's hard to guess what all you are doing (or doing wrong) without it.  Finally, what do you mean by the code is "not working"?  Does it crash, does it put up an error message, does it get the value wrong?   Lastly, why do you use intValue in the comparison and floatValue in the storage?

Answer (score 0):

if you use core data, look here : [Querying max, min and other via Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789033/querying-max-min-and-other-via-core-data)

if you use sqlite, it's a simple sql request :

SELECT MAX(Price)
FROM yourtables
WHERE yourpredicates;

Comment: i want to do it in the objective-c not query.

Comment: so why do you tag your question with "database" ?